# How to assign a SelectList value to an IEnumerable<SelectListItem> property in a model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am attempting to improve the way I create SelectLists in my MVC Model and View.

Someone commented in an earlier version of my code that I had too many uses of `new`. In the model, which is shown below, I do see the use of `new` twice in the definition of the SelectList. However, I do not know how else to do code it and it is the only way I have seen it defined in examples. Is there a better way?

In the model class, I assign the SelectList value to the `IEnumerable<StudentRoster> StudentRosters`, which then is accessible in the View.

This is how I create the DropDownList in the View.

```
<p>Select a campus: @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.SelectedCampus,Model.CampusList)
```

This is how I define the SelectList in the Model.

```
public class SampleViewModel
{           
    // This IEnumerable is a SelectList in the Html.BeginForm() block
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CampusList { get; set; }

    public string SelectedCampus { get; set; }        

    // This list is the "table" shown in the View that the SelectList filters
    public IEnumerable<StudentRoster> StudentRosters { get; set; }        
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult FilterableIndex(string SelectedCampus="MRA")
{
    StudentRosterViewModel vm = new StudentRosterViewModel();

    vm.StudentRosters = db.StudentRosters
        .Where(m => m.Campus == SelectedCampus)     
        .ToList();

    vm.SelectedCampus = SelectedCampus;
    vm.CampusList = new SelectList(new List<string> 
                     {"CRA","DRA","MRA","PRA" });

    return View(vm);
}
```

Is this correct coding or is this an example of picking up a bad habit?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the way your generating the `SelectList`, but having a property `SelectedCampus` and then not binding to it is a bit pointless. It should be just `CampusList = new SelectList(new List<string> {"CRA","DRA","MRA","PRA" });` (omit the last parameter) and then in the view `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCampus, Model.CampusList)`

Comment: Note also you need a parameterless constructor for your view model or your code will throw an exception when you submit the form. And typically its your controller which should be responsible for populating the `SelectList` property, not the view model itself (not so important in your case, but it would be if you were accessing the database in the view model constructor)

Comment: This is where I'm having a disconnect. How is the Controller supposed to know what value I've chosen (by posting the form) and refresh the query accordingly? The use of constructor parameters is the only way I've seen this done so far.

Comment: Because if you use the code I have shown, your binding to your `SelectedCampus`, so in the POST method, the value of `SelectedCampus` will be the value of the option you have selected.

Comment: I had to make some other adjustments in my Controller. Thanks -- that's a neat trick.  However, another question remains: I pulled that constructor code back into the Controller -- and I was told that the Controller should be as thin as possible. I'm posting a revised code block. While it "works" I think it could still be better as far as what code goes where is concerned. Please stand by.

Comment: Thats exactly what your controller should be doing.And there should be an additional line of code - `vm.CampusList = new SelectList(new List<string> {"CRA","DRA","MRA","PRA" });` in there as well. Although its better to refactor that into a separate `private void ConfigureViewModel(SampleViewModel model) { model.CampusList = ... }` method so that in can be called in both the GET and POST methods (if `ModelState` is invalid and you return the view)

Comment: Updated controller & model code. So what is in the controller now would not be considered "fat"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111906/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-rubix-revenge).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your view model, just give the items to the view model when it's constructed and have it generate the SelectListItems from them. @Rubix_Revenge, that's the controller's job.

Whatever,This is carrect way

```
CampusList = new SelectList(new List<string> {"CRA","DRA","MRA","PRA" });
```

Comment: This definitely answers the main question answered about defining the SelectList.